# Apollo Client Cache Sync Issue Between Instances in Next.js with React Apollo through pm2

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo-client, pm2

I'm using Next.js and React Apollo for my application and have set up my application to run with pm2 in a clustered mode with two instances. The problem I'm facing is that when I switch from one user profile to another, the posts from the previous profile still appear due to a lack of cache synchronization between the instances.
I using cache like this

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: splitLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

I start the application with the command `pm2-runtime ecosystem.config.js`.

Here's my ecosystem.config.js file:

```
 module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'web_prod',
            script: 'server.js',
            instances: '2',
            exec_mode: 'cluster',
            watch: false,
            max_memory_restart: '2G',
            autorestart: true,
            env: {
                PORT: 3001,
            },
        },
    ],
};
```

Could you please guide me on how to configure Apollo Client cache to work seamlessly across these two instances or more? Your assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you're only caching in the client then the number of server instances doesn't matter since each will be stateless. If you're caching on the server then you'll need a shared cache (often Redis) between servers.

You describe a problem when switching between user profiles - are posts connected to the user? In other words if you inspect the cache are posts a property of the user or a property of a query? In the latter case you will want to refetch the set of posts when you switch user profiles with a `network-only` cache policy.